# Numerical detection of Cantori

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, differential-equations, continued-fractions, hamiltonian-mechanics

It is known that as parameters vary in Hamiltonian system, KAM tori can break [1,2].

How to construct numerically the breaking tori?

The most relevant paper that I could find is [3,4].

But it uses chaos indicator for its bifurcation plots. I.e., it does not concern itself with actual construction of tori.

[1] *MacKay, R. S.*, Renormalisation in area-preserving maps, Advanced Series in Nonlinear Dynamics. 6. Singapore: World Scientific. xix, 304 p. (1993). [ZBL0791.58002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0791.58002).

[2] *Delshams, Amadeu; de la Llave, Rafael; Seara, Tere M.*, [**A geometric mechanism for diffusion in Hamiltonian systems overcoming in the large gap problem: Heuristics and rigorous verification on a model**](https://doi.org/10.1090/memo/0844), Mem. Am. Math. Soc. 844, 141 p. (2006). [ZBL1090.37044](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1090.37044).

[3] @article{barrio2020distribution,
title={Distribution of stable islands within chaotic areas in the non-hyperbolic and hyperbolic regimes in the H{'e}non--Heiles system},
author={Barrio, Roberto and Wilczak, Daniel},
journal={Nonlinear Dynamics},
volume={102},
number={1},
pages={403--416},
year={2020},
publisher={Springer}
}

[4] @article{aguirre2001wada,
title={Wada basins and chaotic invariant sets in the H{'e}non-Heiles system},
author={Aguirre, Jacobo and Vallejo, Juan C and Sanju{'a}n, Miguel AF},
journal={Physical Review E},
volume={64},
number={6},
pages={066208},
year={2001},
publisher={APS}
}

Comment: I tried to improve the formatting of your citations by using the automatic citation tool, but references [3] and [4] were not found by the system.

Comment: Cantori or KAM tori??

Comment: @YCor Cantori  , as defined e.g. in Mackay "Cantori for symplectic maps near the anti-integrable limit"